# Silverlight passing an array to a web page's dialog arguments

Tags: c#, javascript, silverlight, modal-dialog

I have the following line of code to open a web page modal dialog in C# (Silverlight):

```
var so = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke(
    "showModalDialog", 
    modalWindowUrl, 
    dialogArgs, 
    "dialogWidth:600px;dialogHeight:600px;");
```

Now, code similar to the following is being called on the page I am displaying, and I need to make sure it gets the values I'm trying to pass in (this is a MSCRM web page I don't have control over):

```
dialogArgs.items <-- will be an array I pass in
dialogArgs.items[i].getAttribute("oid") <-- will return something
dialogArgs.items[i].getAttribute("otype") <-- will return something
dialogArgs.items[i].values <-- will return something
```

What I have tried to send in (from my C# code) is this:

```
dialogArgs = @"{items:[{oid:" + id + ",otype:" + type + "}]}";
```

which will result in a JSON string... but I'm guessing this just ends up as a string within the JavaScript and not a JSON object.

Any ideas how I get this to work?

A few side notes:

- I can't get IE to debug the modal dialog that results from this call. I can get the debugging tools displaying, but it won't attach to the page because it cannot refresh it.
- I don't have control over this modal dialog. It's a page that is displayed using MS Dynamics CRM. For that reason I cannot mess with the JavaScript or anything to test stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I won the tumbleweed award for this one! Can't believe how uncommon this scenario seems to be. The solution ended up being quite simple, but not very documented so took me a while to track down. Thought I would share here.

Firstly, a quick search across the internet reveals that we can set this up using the following:

```
var dialogArgs = HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("Object");
```

Which gives you a `ScriptObject` back. For properties:

```
dialogArgs.SetProperty("items", items);
```

Some code for setting up an array and an item should look something like this (I have just created a new GUID for the purpose of this example):

```
var item = HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("Object");
item.SetProperty("oid", Guid.NewGuid()); 
item.SetProperty("otype", "account"); 
var items = HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance("Object");
items.SetProperty(0, item);
```

And finally, just pass that object straight into your dialog window like this:

```
var so = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showModalDialog", lookUpWindow, dialogArgs, "dialogWidth:600px;dialogHeight:600px;");
```